# Joining 2 Hashes/Map/Table into 1 with defined key condition in Freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker

Good Day All,

I face some situation which i have base data like this as hashes/maps/tables
[image]

And my goal is text output like this

[image]

i've tried to have code such a

```js
<#list Detail as d>
<#list Header as h><#if H.Hno == d.DocNo>${h.Hno};${h.Htype};</#if></#list>${d.Seq};${d.Name};<#list Header as h><#if H.Hno == d.DocNo>${h.Hcode}</#if></#list>${d.Status}
</#list>
```

but it said somewhat Hno evaluate null or missing.

Is there any way to solve and efficient way this ?
Appreciate you guys support

Comment: What's `H`? I only see `h` (lower-case) in the code. Maybe `H` indeed has no `Hno` subvariable. Anyway, the error is not related to what you are trying to do, which is joining two tables. The template language is not meant to do such data transformations, and you can only do the brute-force approach which you are trying to implement there already. You should do the join before calling the template.

Comment: @ddekany Sorry my bad, it should be h not H, Thank you for ur info, ive been searching around macro etc. turns out it cant ... if so let me just join in db before calling template ... Thankyou so much